# Is there anyway to extend a jest configuration file?

Tags: jestjs

Within a node app where I'm using Jest to test client side code (testEnvironment: 'jsdom') and server side code (testEnvironment:'node') as well collecting code coverage for both client and server side.

Currently I'm using 4 Jest config files with lots of redundant configuration to accomplish this.

client

```
{
  "bail": true,
  "verbose": true,
  "notify": true,
  "scriptPreprocessor": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./coverage",
    "./dist",
    "./build"
  ],
  "testRegex": "\\.test\\.js"
}
```

client coverage

```
{
  "bail": true,
  "verbose": true,
  "notify": true,
  "scriptPreprocessor": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./coverage",
    "./dist",
    "./build"
  ],
  "testRegex": "\\.test\\.js",
  "collectCoverageFrom": ["**/*.js", "!**/node_modules/**"],
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./coverage",
    "./dist",
    "./build",
    "./test"
  ],
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 100,
      "functions": 100,
      "lines": 100,
      "statements": 100
    }
  }
}
```

server

```
{
  "bail": true,
  "verbose": true,
  "notify": true,
  "scriptPreprocessor": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./coverage",
    "./dist",
    "./build"
  ],
  "testRegex": "\\.test\\.js",
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

server coverage

```
{
  "bail": true,
  "verbose": true,
  "notify": true,
  "scriptPreprocessor": "./node_modules/babel-jest",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./coverage",
    "./dist",
    "./build"
  ],
  "testRegex": "\\.test\\.js",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "collectCoverageFrom": ["**/*.js", "!**/node_modules/**"],
  "collectCoverage": true,
  "coverageDirectory": "./coverage",
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "./node_modules",
    "./coverage",
    "./dist",
    "./build",
    "./test"
  ],
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 100,
      "functions": 100,
      "lines": 100,
      "statements": 100
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this without repeating my configuration 4 times? I've looked at the `preset` configuration option.  Using that I have to create a separate package for each configuration.  Is that the recommended way?

Comment: Did you figure this out? the answer below doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Ionix: I've posted a comment about cascading configs on [this Jest issue about simplifying configuration](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7185#issuecomment-488212347).

Answer (score 23):

Yes, you could define shared `jest.config.js`
and reuse it in your specific configs:

- It's nice to use `<rootDir>` in all paths in your shared config, so those could be reused too.

`client/jest.config.js`

```js
const sharedConfig = require('../jest.config.js');
module.exports = {
  ...sharedConfig,
  'rootDir': './',
}
```

`server/jest.config.js`

```js
const sharedConfig = require('../jest.config.js');
module.exports = {
  ...sharedConfig,
  'rootDir': './',
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

You could also reuse jest defaults if needed: [Jest Documentation - Configuring Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#defaults)

Comment: I tested your solution and it worked great but I have a question, imaging that "client" and "server" are 2 completely different packages, how do you handle shared "setupFiles" and "setupFilesAfterEnv" coming from the same shared package where you have the reusable jest.config.js?

Comment: @mejiamanuel57 you could keep it as separate npm package which would be shared between 2 or N independent packages...

Comment: It looks like this is just using ECMA object spread syntax. I don't think that will allow inheritance of nested options recursively. Properties in the child will fully replace those same properties from the parent, unless you explicitly spread those specific properties as well, down to however many levels deep you want to go.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since Jest v20 you can define config as a JS file and use it to share common parts of the similar configs. [Docs on configuring Jest](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#projects-array-string-projectconfig).

By default Jest looks up for:

- `jest.config.js`
- `"jest"` entry in `package.json`

...and treats the parent directory as a `rootDir`.

Also be sure to check out the `projects` option, which makes it easier to run Jest inside monorepos (e.g. client + server code in one codebase). See this answer for reference: [Testing two environments with jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318115/testing-two-environments-with-jest/42236602#42236602)