# Testing two environments with jest

Tags: jestjs

I'd like to set two different environments and be able to run both in watch mode.

```
|-- /server
|     |-- index.js  <-  Node
|-- /client
|     |-- index.js  <-  jsdom
|-- package.json
```

Actually I run jest twice for each environment, providing a different config file for each:

```
$ yarn test -- --config=server.config.json
$ yarn test -- --config=client.config.json
```

But this doesn't let me run both at the same time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**EDIT (Jan 2018):**

It is now possible to do so (since Jest v20), and the option is called `projects`. Read more about [it the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#projects-arraystring--projectconfig).

Basically you can define an array of your projects you want Jest to be run within:

```
{
  "projects": ["<rootDir>/client", "<rootDir>/server", "<rootDir>/some-glob/*"]
}
```

Just remember every project needs to have its own config. If you want the config to be picked up automatically, put it inside `jest.config.js` file or like usually in `package.json`.

If you prefer placing your config somewhere else (e.g. in `configs/jest.js`), you'll need to point to the path of the config file (with the `rootDir` option set properly):

```
{
  "projects": ["<rootDir>/client/configs/jest.js", "<rootDir>/server/configs/jest.js"]
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Currently this is not possible, but there's an issue for that case: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1206.

Feel free to jump in and leave a comment!

Comment: I see that this is possible with Jest 20+. How do you properly set this up now? Do I need different jest.config.js, for example?

*EDIT*: Ok, so I found a solution:
One way I did it is take my original top-level jest config, and place it in the `projects` array for my original environment, and then define a second config for my Node environment.

That seemed to work with one (1) jest.config.js file defined!

Comment: Great you worked it out! You can also pass an array of paths to your projects, or even a glob, where each project needs to have some kind of config (either `jest.config.js` or `jest` entry in `package.json`).

Answer (score 19):

You can also use [the `@jest-environment` docblock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) to set test environments on a per-file basis:

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

test('use jsdom in this test file', () => {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  expect(element).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Comment: Make sure you restart your test runner when making this change. :)